# ssh先でgit pushできない

Tags: git, ssh

ssh先のUbuntu22.04のサーバーで

```
git push
```

を行おうとすると、

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

と出てpushできません。
サーバーのshellを用いて直接pushすることはできます。

そこで、

```
 ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

を行いました。

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [20.27.177.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-cd305013
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-cd305013
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/bokutotu/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/bokutotu/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/bokutotu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bokutotu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

と出てきました。
このエラーを解決する方法がわかりません。

https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -l -E ecdsa
```

を行いましたが、

```
Invalid hash algorithm "ecdsa"
```

となってしまいました。

予測としては、sshの権限周りの設定がうまくできていないかと思われますが、
要因の推定がうまくできません。

ご回答の程よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score -1):

> サーバーのshellを用いて直接pushすることはできます。

がどういう状況かわかりませんが。

`ssh -Tv git@github.com` 出力結果は、質問文中でリンクされているページの [使用中のキーを持っていることを確認する > 詳細を確認する](https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey#getting-more-details) で例示されている事象と同一に見えます。

つまり、GitHubに登録している公開鍵に対応する秘密鍵を持っていないのだと考えられます。

> この例では、SSH が使用するキーはありませんでした。 「identity file」行の最後の「-1」は、SSH が使用するファイルを見つけることができなかったことを示します。 その後、「Trying private key」の行でもファイルが見つからなかったことが示されています。 ファイルが存在する場合は、これらの行はそれぞれ「1」と「Offering public key」になります。

Answer (score -3):

> Permission denied (publickey).

というエラーは、接続鍵が間違っているか、接続鍵の設定が間違っている場合に出ます
そこらへんを見直してみよう

Comment: 接続鍵は間違っていないと思います、理由としては、サーバー側のシェルを直接叩いた場合は問題なくpushできるためです。
> サーバーのshellを用いて直接pushすることはできます。
というのはその意味です

Comment: いくらあなたがそう思っていても、サーバさんはそうは言ってませんね。直接pushしないってのは,もしかしてサーバにSSHで接続してって話ですか？ならそいつの接続鍵はどーなんでしょ

Comment: 前提の話をしていなかったのですが、sshすると`~/.ssh`のディレクトリへのアクセス権限がなくなるのが直接的な問題だと思っております。そのため、githubにsshしようとする場合にsshの鍵を見つけられずエラーになっています。

Comment: そうおもうなら、それを確認するとかどうにかするとかすればどうでしょう。何を聞きたいのか、ってはなしになりますが。