# ssh先でいくつかのファイルにアクセスできない

Tags: linux, ssh

sshで接続したサーバーの中で一部のディレクトリにアクセスができません。
そのため`git push`などのコマンドが正しく動作していないです。

```
ls ~/.ssh
```

などを実行すると

```
cannot access '/home/username/.ssh': Permission denied (os error 13)
```

と出ます。
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` の`AllowUsers`や~/.sshのディレクトリ内のファイルに`chmod 777` を行ったりしましたが結果は変わりませんでした。

解決策がわかる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。

サーバー側の`~/.ssh`ディレクトリに関して`ls -la`を行った結果は

```
drwx------  2 bokutotu staff    4096 12月  4 11:35 .
drwxr-x--- 46 bokutotu bokutotu 4096 12月  4 16:34 ..
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff     187 12月  4 00:43 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff     557 10月  4 11:45 coral_board
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff     179 10月  4 11:45 coral_board.pub
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff     513 12月  4 02:40 github
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff     179 12月  4 02:40 github.pub
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff    1312 12月  4 00:53 known_hosts
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff     948 10月  4 14:23 known_hosts.old
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff     179 10月  4 11:47 pbcopy
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff     411  5月  7  2022 serial-server.pem
-rw-------  1 bokutotu staff      99  5月  7  2022 serial-server.pem.pub
```

のようになっております。

`ls -ld ~/.ssh`の結果は

```
drwxr-x--- 46 bokutotu bokutotu 4096 12月  4 16:40 .
```

でした

`id`の結果に関しては

```
uid=1000(bokutotu) gid=1000(bokutotu) groups=1000(bokutotu),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare)
```

です。

Comment: ファイルやディレクトリにアクセスできないのは、もしかするとアクセス権がないからかもしれません。アクセス権を確認してください。

Comment: エラーメッセージを見るとディレクトリ自体へのアクセス権がないのではないでしょうか。ファイルだけではなくディレクトリのアクセス権も必要です。

Comment: @sayuri  アクセス権限がないということはわかりました。どのようにアクセス権限を編集すれば良いのでしょうか？`chmod 777 `などをして`~/.ssh`ディレクトリにアクセス権限を与えたつもりなのですが、sshした端末からだと`cannot access '/home/username/.ssh': Permission denied (os error 13)`となってしまします。

Comment: @SugiyamaKoichi ディレクトリへのアクセス権も編集しています。`chmod 777 ~/.ssh`を行っているのですが、結果としては変わりません。

Comment: 状況確認のためにコメントで長く会話が続いていたため、この会話をチャットに移動しました。こちらでよろしくお願いいたします： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141077/discussion-on-question-by-bokutotsuzenu-ssh

Answer (score 1):

環境は[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/92558/ssh%E5%85%88%E3%81%A7git-push%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)と同じサーバーという事でいいでしょうか?
また、問題が発生するのはSSHでログインした時のみで、サーバーのコンソール等からログインした時は問題無いという事でいいでしょうか?

これらが合っているとして、

- SSH接続時のみ発生する
- 単純にPermission deniedとなるだけではなく`(os error 13)` となる

という辺りから、単純なファイル/ディレクトリのpermissionの問題ではありません。
ただ、os error 13はおそらくEACCESの事でしょうから、何らかの権限周りの問題だと思います。
現象からは、SELinuxやAppArmor等の強制アクセス制御が影響しているように思います。
AppArmorやSELinuxの設定はどうなっていますか?

Ubuntu 22.04ならばAppArmorがデフォルトで有効になっているようです。
エラーになった時に`/var/log/syslog`等にAppArmorのログが出力されていませんか?